# How do I manually add IP to my routing?

Tags: openvpn, ip-address, gateway, routing

I need to add an IP to my routing. I'm connected to a lab with Openvpn. My routing looks like this now;

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref   Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0     0   wlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0     0   wlan0
192.168.193.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0     0   tap0
```

I need to add (example) IP 20.20.20.0/24 so I can visit webserver 20.20.20.8 via tap0. I can't get this to work. How do I set up the correct gateway and IP?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/612840/adding-route-on-client-using-openvpn

> D) Bonus option! openvpn also has a up /down directive that allows you to launch a script on connect to vpn this can allow you to do anything you want really. setting dns, routes etc. But it requires you to store the commands in another file.
>
> So if you had the following to your openvpn client config file
>
> script-security 2
>
> up run-stuff-after-vpn-connect.sh
>
> create a file named run-stuff-after-vpn-connect.sh (make sure it has execute permissions. And add:
>
> ## /bin/sh
>
> route add -net 172.16.0.0/24 dev tun0
>   will add the route as soon as the tunnel is up

So you basically put your route to a sh file, for example my_route.sh (I'm assuming 192.168.193.1 is your OpenVPN GW local IP address)

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via 192.168.193.1 dev tap0
```

then add to your OpenVPN client's config file

```
up /your path to/my_route.sh
```

It may not work, so you can also add the route through systemd startup config

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN connection to %i

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --daemon openvpn@%i
ExecStartPost=/your path to/my-add-route.sh
ExecStop=/your path to/my-remove-route.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: dont forget to make your script executable and always use full path for the commands in your scripts. Not 'route' but '/sbin/route' or wherever its placed in your server. use `whereis route` to find out the full path

Comment: Looked at it but it doesn't make sense to me. I've tried the commands like ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via xx.xx.xx.xx but I can't get it to work

Comment: @BButter10 don't forget the `dev tap0` at the end of your `route add` command. Are you getting an error or is it just silently failing? Update your question with `traceroute 20.20.20.8` output.

Comment: Thanks Hollowproc. What I don't understand is that I have to add an IP via a gateway that does not exist.

Comment: ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via (GATEWAY) dev tap0

Comment: But what is my gateway? 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Do a `traceroute` to a host in the 192.168.193.0/24 range and see what the first IP it hits in that range is.

Comment: traceroute to 192.168.193.1 (192.168.193.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  kali (192.168.193.72)  2998.935 ms !H  2998.897 ms !H  2998.889 ms !H

Comment: It's my own IP?

Comment: Ok so `route add 20.20.20.0/24 via 192.168.193.72 dev tap0`.. sidenote if this is for OSCP or other, they have dedicated help that may be more familiar with this specific issue.

Comment: Thank you @Hollowproc, it is for something like OSCP but support is not responding to my messages. I've posted in the forum, contacted the support email.....no response. I did what you said and now I have 20.20.20.0 with gateway KALI. Host is still unreachable. I guess I'll have to wait for a response. It has been over 30 hours though.

Comment: @BButter10 do they have an IRC Channel? That's usually a pretty good place for online help/troubleshooting.

Comment: They do not have an IRC channel like OSCP. I'll wait a few hours and hope I'll get a response.

Comment: if you are using one of common known Linux, like Debian or Centos, just try following command
`VPN_GW=$(ip addr show | grep -B 2 tap0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet ).*?(?= peer)'); [ ! -z "$VPN_GW" ] && ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via $VPN_GW dev tap0 || echo "ERROR: No IP address assigned to tap0 device"` It will look for IP address of tap0 and add the route, or return an error

Comment: sorry, my bad.. The GW IP should be IP of your OpenVPN server, which is in same subnet as IP of your tap0. More likely its 192.168.193.1. So `ip route add 20.20.20.0/24 via 192.168.193.1 dev tap0` should work I guess. Also edited my answer

Comment: Thanks @Shirker, this is what I tried in the first place. It has not worked. This is what's strange to me. It should work?

Comment: It may not work if you dont have NAT enabled on your OpnVPN server.  Something like `-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.193.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <external IP of OpenVPN server>`. As well allowing rule `-A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: as well make sure ip_forward is enabled on your OpenVPN server. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and `sed -i 's@net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0@net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1@g'  /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: you may try to check this article
http://centos.mwzip.com/wiki/OpenVPN_setup for the basic OpenVPN setup on Centos